# Measure RoundTrip TCP latency without changes to application protocol

Tags: c#, networking, latency, tcp

Is there any way (preferably in C#) how to regularly measure connection layer latency (roundtrip) without changing the application protocol and without creating separate dedicated connection - e.g. using some similar SYN-ACK trick like [tcping](http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php) do but without closing/opening connection?

I'm connecting to the servers via given ASCII based protocol (and always using TCP_NODELAY). Servers send me large amount of discrete messages and I'm regularly sending 'heartbeat' payload (but there is no response payload to the heartbeat).
I cannot change the protocol and in many cases I also cannot create more than one physical connection to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that TCP does [windowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option), so this could cause issues when trying to implement an elegant SEQ/ACK solution. (you would want sequence, not synchronize)

[EDIT: Snipped a very overcomplicated and confusing explaination.]

I'd have to say the best way is to use a simple stopwatch method of starting a timer, making a very thin request or poll, and measure the time back from it.  If that query really is the lightest you can make it, then that should give you the minimum amount of time you can reasonably expect to wait, which sometimes more valuable than the ping (which can be misleading).

If you really absolutely need just the network time to machine and back, just use an [ICMP ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for pointing out SEQ/ACK - I guess that will be the way! Any pointer how to use those (on an existing connection, while still using .NET sockets for sending/receiving other data)?
Windowing - it is actually desirable to know about any delays that the current connection has (as soon as the measure mechanism doesn't cause any additional problems - but it hopefully shouldn't).
I *cannot create new connection* => no ICMP ping; I cannot use any tinny request (there is nothing like that in the protocol) :|

Comment: You would have to create a raw socket in promiscuous mode to sense your outgoing traffic if you can't change the netcode.  Pings are going to be the lightest thing to help you see actual network latency.  There is no new connection required for pinging.  It's not a connection-oriented protocol.  You just generate the ping and let it go.  Some machines/routers are set by default to not respond to those though.  Are you saying you can't open a new socket on the local machine?

Comment: Majority of those servers filter out ICMP, so we are using tcping for measuring latency out-of-process. However some of the servers allow just on TCP/IP connection - so once we are connected to receive data, we cannot telnet or tcping to that server.
I was hoping that I'd be able to avoid raw sockets or traffic sniffing - looks like that's not possible in my case:(